# "Duplicate class found" - IntelliJ and .class files

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently imported one of our company's project into IntelliJ Idea (10.5.1). We build and run the project using an *ant* build script and IntelliJ supports that just fine.

However, IntelliJ seems to have a distinct problem when the compile output directory equals the source code directory, ie `.class` files are placed in the same directories as their corresponding `.java` sources.

(Note that I am aware that is not a proper way to go, but tell my boss that. This project is over 15 years old and correspondingly large, too many things depend on it to be this way, there is nothing I can do about that.)

So once things are compiled, IntelliJ detects the `.class` files and adds them to the project tree. The problem here is that it considers them class declarations, thus I get a "duplicate class found" message for each and every class. This doesn't make me unable to work, but it is extremely annoying as you may guess.

I tried making the IDE ignore `.class` files, but apparently that makes it not load any classes at all, including the JRE runtime and anything else located inside of `.jar` files.

Is there any way to make IntelliJ Idea ignore `.class` files which are in the same location as their `.java` sources?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure that you've configured the output directory to the source directory, disable the Exclude of the output directory to see your files.

Comment: I do see the files, the problem is that I see every file twice (IntelliJ displays both the `.java` _and_ the `.class`). In the source view it displays the described error message "Duplicate class found" - which is true from its point of view, but it should ignore the `.class` files in the first place if the `.java` source is there as well. At least that's what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Please provide a sample project to reproduce it.

Comment: Hm, I cannot reproduce this by creating a minimal example project, even though the settings are the same. I will try to find a difference in the project data files themselves.

Comment: Alright, I am fairly sure this is a bug in IntelliJ Idea which I should probably report to them. When I create a new project from existing sources and use the source path that IntelliJ proposes, this problem occurs to me. If I don't do that, but mark the same path as a source path manually after the project has been created, everything works as expected.

Comment: Now I definitely pinned it down. The thing is that I have several modules. For starting the application, I created a library (Project Settings -> Libraries) which also referred to the single module source paths (because the compiled `class` files are needed in the class path). Thus, the module source directories got marked as "libraries", and IntelliJ seems to treat them like jars then, loading the `class` files, which will result in the described problem. The solution is to add a module dependency instead of the modules' source directories.

Answer (score 1):

I coped with this same problem when cloning a project from Bitbucket. To solve it in IntelliJ:

Project Structure > Modules > Source > Source folder > <<"Eliminate the unwanted source folder">>

In my case, I had non-implemented classes in one source folder and a second source folder with the implemented classes (same class names).

I deleted one, built again, and the problem got solved.

Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I had marked my target folder as "Generated Sources Root", unmarking that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

It can be the case that you compile your java code with any other tool. For instance with maven (but directly from one shell).

In such a case, you had generated the `.class` files in another directory so you just need to run `mvn clean` to remove the duplicated compiled files.

If you want to compile your source from several tools, you need to use the same target folder in both, so they do not collide.