# Intellij duplicate class found in the file

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij Ultimate 2016.3.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

After renaming a class: Foo -> FOO (same name but capital letters) - the compiler recognizes two classes and shows them both in project explorer. But in the folder is only one file/class existing.

It seems like Intellij is saving the old name class somewhere an gets the conflikt.

update:
in project explorer i see:

FOO
Foo.java
-> FOO

Anyone else with the same problem?

["Duplicate class found" - IntelliJ and .class files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580384/duplicate-class-found-intellij-and-class-files) does not solve my problem.

Comment: Is the java file renamed as well as the class name inside the file ?

Comment: updated my question. It looks like it is not renamed. But even if i rename it - both classes are still there, but not on the file system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that something went wrong while renaming the classes.

Intellij saves the changes temporary and discards them when operation is done.

I just needed to deactivate this feature. Duplicates were discarded and then i reactivated it.

```
Settings -> System Settings -> Synchronization and unchecked "Use safe write".
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate your problem with version 2017.1 on Ubuntu 16.10 and I am unable to recreate it. I suggest updating or try invalidating cashes / restart.

Comment: Thanks. I also updated to 2017.1 on 16.04 and restarted the system did not work. I guess Intellij saves this information somewhere and something gone wrong while renaming.